# Word for 'Teeth Chattering'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Is there any word or phrase for teeth chattering due to cold?

Comment: Yes, it's _teeth chattering_.

Comment: For other parts of the body, the involuntary motion due to the body's attempt to warm itself is called "shivering", but as far as the teeth go, it's "teeth chattering".

Answer (score 4):

Teeth always ***chatter***.

The movement of the jaw is a specific type of *shiver,* which again is a specific type of *tremor* found in cold-stressed subjects. The shivering reflex is triggered in order to use muscles: heat is a by-product of muscle use.

*Shivering* usually affects more than the just the jaw; and *tremor* applies to more types of small rapid movement than a shiver.